# How to store calendar events received via email on an account without a calendar?

Tags: windows-10, email, sync, calendar, microsoft-account

On my work e-mail, I receive event invitations that don't seem to ever get stored anywhere. Is there a way to fix this?

My company uses a standard cheapo IMAP+SMTP webhost to host employee e-mail. I have mail configured to receive mail from `millimoose@initrode.com`. I also set up a Microsoft account under this address, so I can have contacts, calendar, and OneDrive data - but not e-mail - synchronized separately from my personal stuff. (I.e. I get only mail from initrode.com, I get everything else from Microsoft.)

So far so good, when I enter an event in the Calendar app, it shows up in the web interface for the work account. However, when I receive an event invitation in the mail, it doesn't get added anywhere, no matter what response I choose - Mail just keeps complaining that the event is not in my calendar. Mail also "helpfully" hides the .ics attachment so I can't open it in the calendar app manually, and I can't find any setting in Mail telling it what my default calendar is.

Is there a way to make this setup work? A workaround that springs to mind is just having the Outlook.com account fetch my mail from initrode.com, and sticking to that account for everything. But I'm a little leery about turning over my work email to a third party without approval. (Calendar events are a lot less likely to contain sensitive data.)

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft account you can login to and use outlook.live.com, which

- have calendar app
- this calendar can be linked to local calendar (if you'll login to you Windows at least once with MS-account, not local user)

No, your Mail app have to check e-mail as it was done before

Comment: I’ll try the “log-in once with the Live account” when this next crops up. Unfortunately I’m already working elsewhere and don’t have a set-up that can test this.